# How to add multiple rows to IRfcTable

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

I am trying to pass 2 rows to a BAPI table, but my code is taking only the 2nd row all the times.

I is passing the data as:

```
6 7 8
6 7 8
```

instead of:

```
1 2 3
6 7 8
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
IRfcFunction bapiTEST = _rfcDest.Repository.CreateFunction(strBapi);

IRfcStructure structImport = _rfcDest.Repository.GetStructureMetadata("ZBAPI_A_STRU_ORDER_CLICK").CreateStructure();

structImport.SetValue("NUM1", "000001");
structImport.SetValue("NUM2", "000002");
structImport.SetValue("NUM3", "000003");

IRfcTable tblImport = bapiTEST.GetTable("IMPORT");
tblImport.Insert(structImport);

structImport.SetValue("NUM1", "000006");
structImport.SetValue("NUM2", "000007");
structImport.SetValue("NUM3", "000008");

tblImport.Insert(structImport);
bapiTEST.SetValue("IMPORT", tblImport);

RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(_rfcDest);
bapiTEST.Invoke(_rfcDest);
```

Comment: Don't suppose you have access to the source code of the custom bapi?  My first guess is it is expecting a table with an implicit work area and your remote call isn't handling that correctly.  But I don't have any experience with C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're reusing `structImport`, so the second time you're calling `SetValue` is also affecting the first `structImport` you inserted. Try calling another `CreateStructure()` in between.